# If a value is not found in a Hive table/ DataFrame, then get the next largest value

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have two Hive tables/ Spark Dataframes A and B

```sql
    A
    --------+----------+------+
    product |  date    |  id  |
    --------+----------+------+
    A       | 20200201 |  X   |
    --------+----------+------+
    B       | 20200301 |  Y   |
    --------+----------+------+

    B
    --------+-------+----------+
    product | value | date     | 
    --------+-------+----------+
    A       |   10  | 20191230 |
    --------+-------+----------+
    A       |   5   | 20200310 |
    --------+-------+----------+
    B       |   20  | 20200220 |
    --------+-------+----------+
    B       |   10  | 20200130 |
    --------+-------+----------+
```

And I want a result like

```sql
    --------+----+-------+
    product | id | value |
    --------+----+-------+
    A       |  X |   10  |
    --------+----+-------+
    B       |  Y |   20  |
    --------+----+-------+
```

For a product, if a date from table/ DF A is not found in B, then the row with the previous date is considered to get the *value* column from B to get the result.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach with `SparkSQL` to resolve your question

```scala
      import spark.implicits._

      val dataA = Seq( ("A", 20200201,"X"), ("B",20200301, "Y"))
      val dataB = Seq( ("A", 10, 20191230), ("A",5, 20200310), ("B", 20, 20200220), ("B", 10, 20200130))

      val dfA = sc.parallelize(dataA).toDF("product", "date", "id")
      val dfB = sc.parallelize(dataB).toDF("product", "value", "date")

      dfA.createOrReplaceTempView("ta")
      dfB.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")

      sqlContext.sql(
        """
          |WITH filt AS (
          |SELECT DISTINCT a.product, a.date, a.id, b.value, b.date,
          |RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.product ORDER BY b.date DESC) AS rnk
          |FROM ta AS a
          |JOIN tb AS b ON(a.date != b.date)
          |WHERE a.date > b.date)
          |SELECT filt.product, filt.id, filt.value
          | FROM filt
          | WHERE filt.rnk = 1
          |""".stripMargin).show(truncate = false)
```

with the expected output

```sql
+-------+---+-----+
|product|id |value|
+-------+---+-----+
|B      |Y  |20   |
|A      |X  |10   |
+-------+---+-----+
```